# Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon desktop too many files error

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

After running cinnamon desktop for a while, I eventually get a "too many files open" error.  This typically occurs after leaving my laptop on overnight, or midway thru a day.

Here's my system details:

`$ cat /etc/lsb-release`

```
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.3
DISTRIB_CODENAME=sylvia
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia"
```

The process having the issue is actually the 'cinnamon' executable (pid **29195** below):

`$ ps faux | grep cinnamon`

```
mcrowe    1811  0.0  0.0 438712 22488 ?        Ssl  05:55   0:01      \_ cinnamon-session --session cinnamon
mcrowe    1888  0.0  0.0  11136   312 ?        Ss   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch cinnamon-session-cinnamon
mcrowe    1978  0.0  0.1 559020 30388 ?        Sl   05:55   0:01          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-power
mcrowe    1981  0.0  0.0 334388 19584 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-clipboard
mcrowe    1986  0.0  0.0 408420 20132 ?        Sl   05:55   0:12          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-housekeeping
mcrowe    1990  0.0  0.0 384704 21132 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-wacom
mcrowe    1992  0.0  0.0 409776 21564 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-xsettings
mcrowe    2002  0.0  0.4 711672 101888 ?       Sl   05:55   0:01          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-background
mcrowe    2006  0.0  0.1 539888 30080 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-xrandr
mcrowe    2007  0.0  0.0 722876 23008 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-sound
mcrowe    2009  0.0  0.0 658080 21704 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-color
mcrowe    2012  0.0  0.0 334392 19708 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-cursor
mcrowe    2017  0.0  0.0 668100 23096 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-media-keys
mcrowe    2028  0.0  0.0 408408 19900 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-a11y-settings
mcrowe    2029  0.0  0.0 451856 21284 ?        Sl   05:55   0:05          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-keyboard
mcrowe    2031  0.0  0.0 555868 20500 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-orientation
mcrowe    2034  0.0  0.0 408176 19572 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-screensaver-proxy
mcrowe    2050  0.0  0.0 408428 20384 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-mouse
mcrowe    2051  0.0  0.0 484280 20588 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-automount
mcrowe    2053  0.0  0.0 408420 19700 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-a11y-keyboard
mcrowe    2055  0.0  0.0 454336 23144 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-print-notifications
mcrowe    2410  0.0  0.1 194508 30612 ?        S    05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/cinnamon-launcher --replace
mcrowe   29195 12.9  1.3 2189452 321324 ?      Sl   09:04  36:50          |   \_ cinnamon --replace --replace
mcrowe    2543  0.0  0.1 427132 31948 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00          \_ /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/cinnamon-killer-daemon
mcrowe    4601  0.0  0.2 716320 63272 ?        Sl   05:55   0:07          \_ cinnamon-screensaver
mcrowe    1891  0.0  0.0  43600   372 ?        S    05:55   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch cinnamon-session-cinnamon
mcrowe    2176  0.0  0.0 508852 14252 ?        Sl   05:55   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-printer
mcrowe   24124  0.0  0.0  14224   988 pts/4    S+   13:49   0:00      \_ grep --color --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.git cinnamon
```

There's apparently a per-process limitation of 1024 open files:

`$ ls -1b /proc/29195/fd | wc -l`

```
1024
```

The specific files that are open are in this gist:

`$ lsof -p 29195`

[info.md](https://gist.github.com/drmikecrowe/697edde16e1e310ee986567bb71efad2)

I can recover by pressing Ctrl-Alt-ESC to restart, but I'd like to know what's causing this.  Anybody know the cause?